# How to perform arthemetic with ULARGE_INTEGER

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have an application where i continuously check a disk space and compare it with a particular value. Now the disk space is calculated by:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER p1;
ULARGE_INTEGER p2;
ULARGE_INTEGER p3;
GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(".", &p1, &p2, &p3);
```

Now from above method i get the free available space in variable p3. Now how can i compare(arithmetic operations as well) it with an normal integer value. Additionally this code must work in 32 bit as well as 64 bit platform. Or if there is any other option to calculate the free disk space? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

ULARGE_INTEGER was how the Windows API would represent a 64-bit value before compilers had a native 64-bit type.

Today, on Windows with the Visual C++ compiler it's safe to do pointers cast between `ULARGE_INTEGER*` and a 64-bit native type such as `uint64_t*` or `unsigned long long*`.

```
int compile_time_assert[(sizeof(ULARGE_INTEGER) == sizeof(unsigned long long)) ? 1 : -1];

unsigned long long freebytes = 0;
unsigned long long totalbytes = 0;
unsigned long long totalfree = 0;
GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(".", (ULARGE_INTEGER*)&freebytes, (ULARGE_INTEGER*)&totalbytes, (ULARGE_INTEGER*)&totalfree);
```

Otherwise, if you'd like to avoid the cast hackery, you can just do this instead:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER p1 = {0};
ULARGE_INTEGER p2 = {0};
ULARGE_INTEGER p3 = {0};
unsigned long long freebytes = 0;
unsigned long long totalbytes = 0;
unsigned long long totalfree = 0;
GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(".", &p1, &p2, &p3); 

freebytes = p1.QuadPart;
totalbytes = p2.QuadPart;
totalfree = p3.QuadPart;
```

Comment: Concerning "ULARGE_INTEGER was how ... Windows ... represent a 64-bit value ...before compilers had a native 64-bit type" --> Looks like this was introduced in Windows 95 - four years or so before C99.  Was it used earlier?

Comment: @chux - If I recall, MSVC compiler introduced the `__int64` type around 1998 during the Visual Studio 6.0 days and likely before C99. `(U)LARGE_INTEGER` was needed for a handful of APIs such as the disk space and `QueryPerformanceCounter` APIs. And those APIs probably existed during the Windows NT 3.5 days (1994).

Answer (score 4):

This is assuming that your program is targeting Windows where the `ULARGE_INTEGER` type is defined in the Win SDK.

`ULARGE_INTEGER` is a union that includes a `QuadPart` member that is the 64-bit value of the integer. So just do something like:

```
if (p1.QuadPart < p2.QuadPart) ...
```

This will also work in 32-bit builds because 64-bit integer types have been supported by compilers targeting Win32 for a long time now (maybe since the dawn of Win32).

Comment: If that wasn't the active member then this is UB.

Comment: It might be UB by the C standard, but it's not UB for Win32.